# Why doesn't Google return the main page when searching for the exact domain?

Tags: url, google-search, search

I'm trying to figure out a problem for one of my clients. I have to mention that I've not developed the website and the company that has done the development can not be contacted anymore.

The the website's domain is `www.sav-ante.fr`. The odd thing with this website is that when you type: "sav-ante" in the Google search box (french Google), the URL which is returned is `www.sav-ante.fr/en/contact/contact-form.html‎`.

Is there any one who can explain to me what king of configuration I have to add/modify in order for the returned URL to be `www.sav-ante.fr/fr` (which is how the DNS is configured).

Comment: Do you know if you have a Google Webmasters Tools account? If you do, you should create a sitemap.xml for your entire site and Google will better understand the structure of your website.

If you do not have a Google Webmasters Account you can do so easily by heading to: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=fr (which is the French verison for you).

You need to have a sitemap.xml page created and indexed by Googlebot (the spyder that crawls pages).

If you have already setup for your website to be indexed by Google and it has not been, be patient Google will get to your site!

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The sitemap alreayd existed but after your suggestion I have made modifications in order to indicate highest priorities to the "main" pages.

Comment: That's great! I'm glad that I could help and I believe you are headed in the right direction here. Best wishes!

Comment: frederique, you don't seem to have a sitemap.xml at the usual address. If you have named you sitemap.xml file something other than the norm, then you need to make sure you submit it in Google webmaster tools and idealy also create a robots.txt file where you have identified the address of the sitemap.xml. If you do not take these steps, Google will not find your sitemap.xml

Comment: @Moonbot : Thanks for your help. I've actually submitted several times the sitemap to google via the google webmaster tools, but each time I analyse the site it returns an error... I don't really know the site architecture so I'm checking with the developer to ensure that the actual files are stored at the right place. Hopefully that will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Google is a search engine, not a DNS server.  If you want to see how DNS is configured for a name, type that name into your browser's location.  It will find the web server attached to that name.

Google uses "bots" to visit all the pages of a website and indexes the words it finds on each page.  When you search for a term like "sav-ante", it looks through all the pages for that term, ranks them, and returns them in sorted order.

So if you want a term to go to a particular page, use that term on the page and in the meta tags.  Also, have other websites link to that page because Google's Page Rank increases the rank of pages according to the number of links to it.

Comment: Also, if you have not created a sitemap.xml file and directed Google to it's location on your server, indexing can take a long time. Head to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=fr to sign-up or log-in. You will find the sitemap option under the 'Optimisation' link to the left of the page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After analyse of the pages, it seems that the meta were not filled correctly for mosts of the pages (some didn't even had meta). I'll take your suggestion into account and make the modification to the concerned pages.

Comment: Remember that you can also demote pages from being 'Sitelinks' (showing up under your website's results) if you run into this problem with a lesser important page showing up in the 'Sitelinks' under your website in search results this is an option that many people turn to. Here is a link to another Google Webmasters help document regarding 'Sitelinks': http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=fr&answer=47334

Comment: @toughskin : thanks for your update. I'll give it a try once i've check with the customer if this could be a valid option.

Comment: Let me know if this helps you. I'm interested... Call me curious!